# WordPress pages specified Menu

Tags: php, wordpress

Dears,
I need to customize pages in header and footer
so I write

```
`<?php 

$args = array('theam_location' => 'Primary');

 ?>

<?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?>`
```

in header

And write

```
`<?php

$args = array('theam_location' => 'Footer' );
?>


<?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?>`
```

in footer

And in Functions PHP

```
 `register_nav_menus(array(
'Primary' => __('Primary Menu1'),
'Footer' => __('Footer Menu2'),
));`
```

Then I customize the pages from WordPress dashboard; when I put 5 pages in header menu and 2 pages in footer menu; tshowsl result is show 2 pages put in footer in both Footer and Header Bar!!

WordPress 4.9.8
Advise Please.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing you forgot to check the checkbox for header and footer menu separately.

**Header**

```
<?php 

    $args = array('theme_location' => 'Primary');

?>

<?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?>
```

**Footer**

```
<?php
    $args = array('theme_location' => 'Footer' );
?>


<?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?>
```

Please check the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.. no I check it for sure in both header and footer menu

Comment: i mean check primary with header and footer for footer!

Comment: oooh!! That's Work, One million Thank you

Comment: glad to help you :)